The Emails Contains "-" Classified as Invalid
I faced a problem while I was building a tool that can create a spreadsheet and then send it as an attachment via email that the spreadsheet was not shared with the person I sent the email to because he is not a viewer or have permission, so add this line
SpreadsheetApp.openById(DesID).addViewers(emailsToAdd);
to share the file with after sending the email, its worked well unless the emails that contain "-" for example someone@companyname-country.com, this is the error msg

Exception: Invalid email: someone@companyname-country.com

I thought that there is an issue with the email so I changed the email with an email that didn't contain "-" and it worked then tried to share the file using this
DriveApp.getFileById(DesID).addViewers(emailsToAdd);  

and its worked even the email contains "-".  but the issue is that the sharing is sent in an email, the SpreadsheetApp way above didn't notify the person and its look more professional and less annoying, DriveApp way takes a huge time and slower, anyone can help how to share the file using Spreadsheet app without "-" error?
var SuppliersEmailsLastRow = SuppliersEmails.getLastRow();
var EmailsData = SuppliersEmails.getRange(1, 1, SuppliersEmailsLastRow, 3).getValues(); // create an array of data 

      var emailsToAdd = [];
      for (var nn = 0; nn < EmailsData.length; ++nn) {
      if (EmailsData[nn][1] == SupplierNameString) {
        // Found the supplier, extract emails
        var emailsString = EmailsData[nn][2].toString().trim(); // Ensure to trim whitespace

        if (emailsString !== '') {
          // Split emailsString by comma and handle each email
          var emailsArray = emailsString.split(",");

          // Trim each email and add to emailsToAdd if valid
          emailsArray.forEach(function(email) {
            var trimmedEmail = email.trim();
            if (trimmedEmail !== '') {
              emailsToAdd.push(trimmedEmail);
            }
          });
        }

        console.log("Supplier Selected: " + SupplierNameString + ", Emails: " + emailsToAdd.join(", "));
        break; // Exit the loop once found
      }
    }
    // Log emailsToAdd to verify content
    console.log("Emails To Add:", emailsToAdd);
      SpreadsheetApp.openById(DesID).addViewers(emailsToAdd); First way
      //DriveApp.getFileById(DesID).addViewers(emailsToAdd); Secound way

